# Finding roots of function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Consider the function $$f(x)=(2x-9) \cdot 2 \cdot e^{\frac{x^3}{3}-9x+ \frac{46}{3}}$$ Now, the only root to this function is $x=9/2$

I find it quite easy to find this exact root, I will start by saying. Usually i would solve this kind of problem using a CAS. But I would like to know if any of you guys know a way to find the roots by hand.
Probably, what I'm actually looking more for, is a way to show that there are none other roots than $x=9/2$.

Also, I have discovered the fact that $f(x)$ tends to zero as $x$ tends to $-\infty$.

So again, a way to solve $$0=(2x-9) \cdot 2 \cdot e^{\frac{x^3}{3}-9x+ \frac{46}{3}}$$ by hand.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $e^{\frac{x^3}{3}-9x+ \frac{46}{3}}$ is always positive. So the only possibility to be $f(x)=(2x-9) \cdot 2 \cdot e^{\frac{x^3}{3}-9x+ \frac{46}{3}}=0$ is $2x-9=0,$ which gives you the answer you have obtained.

Comment: And even if one were to allow imaginary numbers, so that $e^\text{something}$ might not be positive, it would still never be $0$, and that's enough.

Comment: Of course, thank you! Didn't think of the whole factor that generally...

Answer (score 1):

$$e^{\text{anything}} \ne  0$$